# AR model notation for non-consecutive PACF values?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, notation, acf-pacf

I am fairly new to time series analysis, and I was learning from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-2C4eO4cPQ&list=PLvcbYUQ5t0UHOLnBzl46_Q6QKtFgfMGc3&index=5) on AR.

The process's PACF has non-zero values at lag `t-1`, `t-2`, `t-4`, and `t-12`, and the model is illustrated as a function `mt=β0+β1mt-1+β2mt-2+β4mt-4+β12mt-12+εt`.

What would be the appropriate notation for this AR model?
AR(12)? AR(1,2,4,12)?

All the examples I have seen so far assumes that PACF values are consecutively non-zero, until it shuts off at a certain point, like at lag `t-3`. In that case I understand it's going to be AR(3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR(12) is the standard notation. You can call it restricted AR(12), as some coefficients preceding the last one are restricted to zero.